# GTK - Custom shaped window

Tags: pygtk, gtk3, gtkmm

I'm looking for a way to create custom shaped window with a hole like for example like the one of BS-Player:

[image]

The area between the gray and the blue part is both transparent and click-through. I seek to implement similar functionality, for example having a square window with a square "hole" in it. Can this be achieved with GTK(C/C++, Python etc)?

Comment: It should be possible but will require direct drawing using Gdk functions.